# Propel treats TINYINT(1) as boolean when reverse engineering

Tags: mysql, boolean, propel, tinyint

I've got a field "paymentmethod" in my MYSQL DB which can hold values from 0 to 9. So i use a TINYINT(1). But for some reason when i reverse engineer the DB with Propel it creates a BOOLEAN which it is not.

What's the proper approach to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *reverse engineer the DB with Propel* ? values in `TINYINT(1)` can only be `1` or `0`.

Comment: IMO `TINYINT(1)` can store `-9` to `9` and `UNSIGNED`: `0-9`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a known bug in Propel. [Here](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues/36) is the discussion. I guess you just need to update Propel.